# how to access a variable from another executable if they are executed at the same time?

Tags: c, unix, io-redirection, command-line-arguments

I have two different executable files called main1 and main2. in the first main1, I have `int main(int argc, char **argv)` parameters which I took the input. and i want to send them to the main2 which I will check the inputs and display them. but the problem is i need to execute them at the same time, separately in Iterm like:

```
./main1 "asd" | ./main2
```

should I use malloc to store it in the memory and call it from the other main? if so how can I do it?
I cannot change the way I am executing them. all I can do is create my library or allocate memory.

Comment: If you are using a pipe just print to stdout on main1 and read on main2, this is what pipe do, connect output of left to input of right

Comment: You are using a pipe `|`. This creates a redirection, it redirects the `stdou` stream from `main1` to `stdin` of `main2`. Just choose a format in which you want to send data, and send it. Use `printf`/`fwrite(... stdout)`/etc.  in `main1` and read the data using `scanf`/`getc`/etc. in `main2`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this shell statement

```
./main1 "asd" | ./main2
```

the pipe symbol (`|`)  connects the standard-output of its left-side argument to the standard-input of its right side argument.

So to send data from `main1` to `main2` just let `main1` write to the pre-opened `FILE*` `stdout` and have `main2` read from the pre-opened `FILE*` `stdin`. "pre-opened" refers to the fact that those two streams are opened automatically by the C runtime-system when a C program starts.

To access the argument passed `main1` inside `main1` define its `main()` like this

```
int main(int argc char ** argv)
```

and do

```
  for (int i = 1; i < argv; ++i)
  {
    /* to for example print the arguments (to standard-output) do: */
    fputs(argv[i], stdout);
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

**You can't use malloc at all.**

Malloc allocates memory on the heap of the current programn but the memory of  "main1" is not shared with the memory of "main2", so you have no way to access it his way.

It is quite a weird thing to do, but if you really need to pass the "asd" string to main2 wihtout using arguments, I suggest you to look for IPCs, and more precisely, shared memory.
This will allow you to declare a portion of memory that will be public on your computer, and any process will be able to access it.

Beware though, that this memory isn't protected against multiple access natively, you need to use semaphores (shared memory mutexes).

You can check the answer of this post for a basic example of how to do this (even though it works with forks and not 2 different processes, it's still the same use case)

And if you want to see what you are doing, when testing, as these memory chunks are computer scoped (and not just computer), you have ways to observe them by the terminal. I suggest you to read this man page and try yourself http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/ipcs.1.html

Finally, if you always launch your programs as so, using the pipe could be nice too ;)

Comment: so is there a no way for me to pass the char without IPCs, like chained lists, binary tree or pointed functions etc. wont work? I never seen this double executing and i have no idea how to do this.

Comment: There is no way to pass informations from a software to another by using "normal" memory". You can either use IPCs, or that pipe you have (only if you are sure your processes will always be launched so)

Answer (score 1):

If I understood your requirement correctly, then it is as follows: you want the output of main1 to go as input to main2, right ?

If the above is the case, then the pipe operator you used does exactly what you require, it redirects the output of main1 to the input of main2

Answer (score 1):

If you want to reuse input, then you can use bash script to take common input. Later you can use those common input to call any number of `main()` function of different program you want.
This is just one possible solution. This might be not applicable to your case.

Reference - https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/89332/how-to-run-more-than-one-program-in-a-single-script